# connection pool log in tomcat

Tags: java, servlets, connection-pooling

I am new to connection pool and want to get a log of connection pool before and after hitting the db.

I've created a connection pool using tomcat. Is there any way i can see status of connection pool ie. no of availabel connections before accessing the database, in between accessing the db and after closing the connection pool?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in functionality in tomcat to do this. You can have this functionality by installing java-monitor ( http://java-monitor.com/forum/install.php ).

Here is a live demo of the things you can see http://java-monitor.com/forum/livedemo.php